# Circular reference between class

Tags: delphi, oop, circular-reference

i need develop the next diagram class:
[image]

I wrote code, but, have problems of circular unit reference.

The XmlFileManager Class contains:

```
unit XmlFileManager;
interface
uses
  xmldom, XMLIntf, msxmldom, XMLDoc, SysUtils, DateUtils, Classes, Dialogs,
  XmlEnpManager;
type
  TXmlFileManager = class
  private
    [...]
    xmEnp: TXmlEnpManager;
    xmEnpInicial: TXmlEnpManager;
    xmEnpFinal: TXmlEnpManager;
[...]
end.
```

The abstract class, XmlNodeManager:

```
unit XmlNodeManager;
interface
uses
  xmldom, XMLIntf, msxmldom, XMLDoc, SysUtils, DateUtils, Classes, Dialogs,
  XmlFileManager;
type
  TXmlNodeManager = class
   protected
        { sgy alias para strategy }
        sgyIterator: Integer;
        sgyContext: TXmlFileManager;
        sgyAttributes: TStringList;
        sgyNode: IXMLNode;
[...]
end.
```

And the XmlEnpManager concrete class:

```
unit XmlEnpManager;
interface
uses
  xmldom, XMLIntf, msxmldom, XMLDoc, SysUtils, DateUtils, Classes, Dialogs,
  XmlNodeManager;
type
  TXmlEnpManager = class (TXmlNodeManager)
    public
        constructor Create(aContext: TXmlFileManager); overload; override;
        constructor CreateInicial(aContext: TXmlFileManager); reintroduce; overload;
        constructor CreateFinal(aContext: TXmlFileManager); reintroduce; overload;
[...]
end.
```

The builds fails with error:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] XmlNodeManager.pas(7): F2047 Circular unit
>   reference to 'XmlFileManager'

Any ideas how to solve this problem ?.

Comment: This is a right royal pain in the butt. Programmers familiar with other languages wonder what on earth we are talking about. Why is this even an issue? Circular references lead you inexorably to putting all your code in the same unit. Ever wonder why Delphi source files tend to be so big? Look at some of the VCL units. Utter monsters. In no small part this is why Delphi executables are so immense in size. Recent RTTI changes have made this worse. Oh sure, you can use interfaces to break dependencies. But that's classic tail wagging dog. It blows.

Answer (score 5):

Put `TXmlFileManager` and `TXmlNodeManager` in both the same `unit` and the same `type` section, then make sure that `type` section starts with this class forward: `TXmlNodeManager = class;`

See the official documentation: [Forward Declarations and Mutually Dependent Classes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Forward_Declarations_and_Mutually_Dependent_Classes).

```
unit XmlFileManagerAndXmlNodeManager;
interface
uses
  xmldom, XMLIntf, msxmldom, XMLDoc, SysUtils, DateUtils, Classes, Dialogs,
[...]

type
  TXmlNodeManager = class;

  TXmlFileManager = class
  private
    [...]
    xmEnp: TXmlEnpManager;
    xmEnpInicial: TXmlEnpManager;
    xmEnpFinal: TXmlEnpManager;
[...]

  TXmlNodeManager = class
   protected
        sgyIterator: Integer;
        sgyContext: TXmlFileManager;
        sgyAttributes: TStringList;
        sgyNode: IXMLNode;
[...]
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, easiest way is to have all classes in same unit.

Comment: That's possibility. Depends on your coding standards if you want to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

Although putting all classes in the same unit is a perfect solution, you might consider breaking the mutual reference by interfacing at least one of the classes, defining that interface in a separate unit and letting the other unit refer to the unit with the interface in its interface section. Then you can move the first unit reference from the interface to the implementation.The creation of an instance will then be done in the implementation section,  where a mutual reference is allowed, but thus breaking the mutual reference in the interface section, which is not allowed, as you already noticed. This allows you to keep both classes in a separate unit, should that be required.
Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If the reference between the units is in the implementation section instead of the interface section then this will work.

You could create a base class in another unit with no out going reference and reference it from the interface and cast into the actual class on demand by adding the specific unit reference to the implementation section.

Comment: No, it won't, because of the dependencies in the code posted. Two of the classes are going to have to be in the same unit.

Comment: Or they have to be the descendants of a class in a third unit.

Answer (score 0):

In XMLNodeManager, Make:

`sgyContext: TObject;`

Then you don't need to use the unit XmlFileManager in interface. Use it in the Implementation section's Uses clause. When using sgyContext in the implementation code, cast it to TXmlFileManager(sgyContext).

Comment: This is a terrible idea. It means you have to have ugly typecasts all over the place, and the compiler can't catch any errors (you can pass a `TButton` by mistake, and it will allow it and try to cast the button as a `TXMLFileManager` - it will compile and run, but will almost certainly blow up at runtime).

Comment: sgyContext is not something that is passed around frequently via a parameter. It's a member and the member can be set in the constructor or in a utility function where there can be code that checks the class type before setting it. Once set correctly, there is no chance of error. Sometimes when you must have units which must be separated, this kind of technique might work. I understand that from a "purist" point of view, this is a no, no. But we are looking at all possible solutions and this is a solution.

Comment: Nope. :-) You're working harder to implement a bad idea than you would to do it properly in the  first place. Besides having to typecast it all over the place, you've now added code to prevent accidentally passing in the wrong type *at runtime*, when doing it properly would allow the *compiler to check it first* and prevent the mistake in the first place. Bad code now piled on top of bad code does not make better code. This is not a solution - it's smelly code piled on top of smelly code to implement a poor solution.

Comment: To clarify: This is the equivalent of the coder who decides to implement a generic-type solution by accepting a base class as a parameter to a method, and then litters the code with `if MyParam is TClassA then...else if MyParam is TClassB then...else if...`, which is a poor implementation. Accepting a generic `TObject` as a parameter and then having to say `if not (MyParam is TheSpecifTypeItShouldHaveBeen) then` to work around it is simply poor implementation.